# nginx - response based on the requested header

Tags: nginx, server-configuration

I have nginx 1.0.8 installed. 
here is my problem:
I have 2 files : *file1.js* and *file2.js*. the requested path is something like this:

> www.mysite.com/files_dir/%user%/file.js

If the requested header : "**X-Header**" exists and has the value "**OK**" then the responded content should be file1.js else file2.js.

The files are situated in "**html/files_dir**" and %user% is a set of directories that represents the usernames registered through my service.

How do I configure this in nginx? I'm not interested in php, asp or similar technologies only if it's possible with nginx.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map` lets you define a variable's value based on another variable. `map` should be declared at `http` level (i.e. outside of `server`):

```
map $http_x_header $file_suffix {
  default "2";
  OK      "1";
};
```

Then the following `location` should do the trick using your new variable `$file_suffix`

```
location ~ ^(/files_dir/.+)\.js$ {
  root html;
  try_files $1$file_suffix.js =404;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with nginx very easily. This is example:

```
location /files_dir/ {

    set $file = file2.js;
    if ( $http_x_header = OK ) {
        set $file = file1.js;
    }
    rewrite ^(/files_dir/.*)/file.js$ $1/$file last;

}
```

You could read about HTTP variables in NGINX [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER) , and about nginx rewrite module [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

Comment: thanks you're answer was also good but set $file = file2.js; is without "=".. just set $file file2.js;