# Python Pyramid increase request timeout

Tags: python, timeout, pyramid

I'm working on a [Python Pyramid](https://trypyramid.com) rest api and in one of the requests I need to process an excel and for each line of it I get the GPS coordinates and do a lot of validation, this means this only request may take some 10 minutes to process and I need to return a response to the caller with a json. I can't send it via WebSocket of anything else.

My question is: how do I increase the timeout for this request? This is my method:

```
@view_config(route_name='client_api_upload',
             request_method='POST',
             renderer='json',
             permission='upload client')
def client_api_upload(request):

    client_id = request.POST['client_id']
    filename = request.POST['file'].filename
    input_file = request.POST['file'].file
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    new_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())+extension
    file_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), new_file_name)

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)

    importer = ClientBuildingImporter(client_id=client_id, db_session=request.dbsession)
    importer.import_building_from_excel(excel_file_path=file_path)

    return importer.import_result
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: HTTP isn't designed to work like that, it's assumed that responses are always available promptly.  maybe have one endpoint for submitting files and another for getting results?  the client would need to poll the result end point until it actually gets a useful result.  that said, how can you ever take 10 minutes to parse an excel file?  they can only ever have a million rows (or something like that) so you should be able to churn through all rows in a couple of seconds at most

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's Pyramid closing the connection, more likely it's the webserver (Apache/Nginx etc.) which serves your application. Pyramid itself is usually happy to just chug along as long as it is necessary.

I agree with @SamMason that there are better (but more complex) ways to properly execute long-running tasks, but in some controlled circumstances it may be fine to have a long-running request which does a lot of processing. I've had a few migration/maintenance scripts which took hours to finish, worked just fine.

The trick to keep all the participants (webserver, proxies, browser, etc.) happy is to make sure that there's a trickle of data returned by your application, don't let the HTTP connection just sit there idle.

With Pyramid, unfortunately, streaming requests is not completely straightforward but there are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502194/pyramid-stream-response-body) [resources](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/2625) which may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is not to execute long running tasks in the requests.

What you can do is

- Make an initial request to kick off the task, returns immediately. This request writes the task to a database.
- Have a background worker process (e.g. Celery) to process tasks
- Have a front end polling / JavaScript / redirect loop to check if the background process has completed the task