# How can I fix ESOCKETTIMEDOUT / ECONNRESET errors in Node.js processes

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, network-programming, node-http-proxy

This is a fairly complex situation so I'll just describe the big picture. We've been having errors for weeks now, so any ideas would be appreciated.

We have four network hops:

```
client (Node.js)
|
AWS ELB
|
routing proxy service (Node.js)
|
Squid proxy
|
the internet
```

We are observing the following errors:

- Client

  - ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
  - Socket hangup
  - Truncated responses (partial JSON, cut off at some point in the middle)
  - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
  - In extreme cases, we see network errors with our Postgres and Redis connections too
- ELB

  - Sometimes we observe the surge queue fills up and drops connections.
    This appears to have been solved by launching more router boxes.
- Routing proxy

  - ECONNRESET
  - Timeouts
  - EMFILE

What have we tried?

- Increasing Node.js HTTP agent `maxSockets` value
- Increasing max open file `ulimit` value
- Increasing TCP `somaxconn`
- Monitoring connection pool sizes (typically this is in normal range)

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I can see all errors are network related, I doubt this is from Redis side, what  is the purpose of using squid and nodejs router, I guess you have multiple services, and you are creating a service pools to direct incoming connection for the right node, I suspect that the error might exist there, how much traffic volume do you have?

Comment: @AbdullahShahin Yeah, the router is sending things to different nodes based on custom HTTP headers. The intention was to split out the routing logic from the client, but we seem to have given ourselves some networking headaches in the process. Our traffic volumes are fairly low in networking terms, around 150-200 requests per second.

Comment: And yes, I also doubt the error is with redis and Postgres. I just wanted to mention it because it seems the problem we're causing is severe enough to effect connections made by other well-trusted libraries.

Comment: so, you are passing the traffic into reverse proxy, probably to hide your end points, and then this traffic is going to nodejs thread to examine their headers, right, how do you examine request headers in nodejs, are you sure all headers are present when they reach node router, how does node router deal with requests after it knows where they are going, I assume you are hitting a request on the ELB right, and on the callback you are respond back to squid, right

Comment: @AbdullahShahin we're relying on `node-http-proxy` (https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to do most of the work in the router process

Comment: based on my experience I can suggest here is to replace squid + nodejs router with nginx as it can do both, if the amount of traffic is big enough, nodejs proxy might not be good solution here as its very hard to scale and its a bottleneck and SPOF at the same time, besides, you are creating additional TCP sockets even they are in different levels, this link might give you a hint how can you implement this from previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168377/nginx-response-based-on-the-requested-header all you need is to create streams for each of your services. best luck bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79439/discussion-between-michael-mcloughlin-and-abdullah-shahin).

Comment: I left you a comment in the chat room

Comment: have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: @Cmag we rewrote the thing in Go! It's working fine :)